# Linear Regression. Interpret weights as an effect on a prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

In a basic linear regression, can I use the weights of each explanatory variable to describe their relative effects on the predicted value? If parameter A has a weight of 100, and parameter B has a weight of 10, can I say that parameter A has 10 times more effect on the outcome than parameter B?

An example: From a weather data set, I used two parameters, humidity and pressure, to make a prediction on temperature.

When I plot humidity vs. temperature, there's a very clear inverse relationship between the two. That is, the scatter plot tends down and to the right.

When I plot pressure vs. temperature, there's no relationship at all. The pressure in this report has very little variance, and the scatter plot is nearly vertical.

Based on those two plots, I intuit that changes in humidity have an effect on the high temperature, while changes in pressure have almost no effect.

I built a linear regression model (gradient descent, by hand, in Octave). Humidity had a weight of -.32386. Pressure had a weight of -.02219. Humidity's weight was 14.6 times larger than pressure's weight.

Based on that, can I state that parameter Humidity has nearly 15 times more effect on Temperature than parameter Pressure?

Forgive what must seem like a very amateur question. If you can give a relatively simple answer and point me toward resources where I can learn more, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One item I forgot to add. I normalized all three vectors before running the linear regression model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a basic linear regression, can I use the weights of each
>   explanatory variable to describe their relative effects on the
>   predicted value? If parameter A has a weight of 100, and parameter B
>   has a weight of 10, can I say that parameter A has 10 times more
>   effect on the outcome than parameter B?
>   Blockquote

Somewhat yes. Precisely it means if A changes by one unit the outcome will change 100 times, on average (while B is frozen because it is a multiple linear regression -> you have more than one independent variable).

There are tons of examples and blogs explaining it, see for example [here](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-regression-coefficients/) .
Also you can analyze your regression model more by doing some statistical tests like identifying how variables are correlated using Variance Inflation Factors and estimate the statistical significance (p-value, F-test), here is a very nice [intro](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/347).

> An example: From a weather data set, I used two parameters, humidity
>   and pressure, to make a prediction on temperature.

I do not see any problem with your analysis. As you said you see an inverse correlation between humidity vs. temperature in your plot as well as via your -.32386 weight. While the weight of -.02219 for pressure is nearly zero and negligible and obviously you won't see such relationship between pressure-temperature.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bit of oversimplification in your analysis. Comparing the values of two parameters doesn't really make sense, as different parameters might have different [dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis), and by comparing parameters with different dimensions you are saying the equivalent to: *this height of this building is two times higher than the weight of this car*.

[This question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/30302/linear-regression-and-scaling-of-data/30485#30485) asks a similar thing, and the most reasonable choice to me is to do it with the scaled variables (that are dimensionless) instead of the measured variables, that have dimensions.